# starting multiple workers in Procfile (development environment vs Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job, foreman

I have a simple Procfile that reads:

```
web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT
worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

On Heroku, this will launch N worker tasks, where N is whatever I've scaled it to be.

On my development system,

```
$ foreman start
```

will only launch one worker task.  If I want to launch three workers, I need a Procfile that looks like:

```
web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT
worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

This is a somewhat pedantic question, but if I want my development environment to behave like my Heroku environment, what's the best way to launch N worker tasks?  Is the approved way to create (e.g.) Procfile_local and use it via `foreman -f Procfile_local`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ah.  Who would have guessed that there's an online [man page for foreman](https://ddollar.github.io/foreman/)? ;)

```
foreman start --concurrency="web=0,worker=6"
```

Does the trick nicely. No need to have a separate Procfile.

Comment: Excellent! I put this in my .foreman config file so I would not have to specify this with each command: `concurrency: web=1,worker=2 \n port: 7500`.  Thanks for the tip fearless_fool.

Answer (score 4):

Latest Foreman has renamed the option to `--formation`.

So, it's:

```
foreman start --formation="web=1,worker=2"
```

[Source](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/blob/master/lib/foreman/cli.rb)